# How to show Object Detection Boundary Boxes with Tensorflow and React Native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm building a react native app which uses a custom trained model to identify objects.

I have done all the setup, camera is working, we exported our Model for Tensorflow (json + bin files) and hosted them on our Webserver to load them inside the app via "tf.loadGraphModel" (so far so good)

Calling a prediction, doing some transformations, gives me the array with the chances of what the model thinks is most accurat. Is it possible to show boundary boxes for the prediction using tensor flow for react native with the expo camera attached (real time at having the video feed open) and if so how.

Also, is it possible to get the prediction class any way easier, or is this the way to go ?

My Screen currently looks like this

```js
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

function DetectionScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [tfReady, setTfReady] = useState(false);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const [modelReady, setModelReady] = useState(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [detectionModel, setDetectionModal] = useState(null);

  let textureDims;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1920,
      width: 1080,
    };
  } else {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1200,
      width: 1600,
    };
  }

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const loadTensor = async () => {
        await tf.ready();
        setTfReady(true);

        let model = null;
        let hasModel = false;

        try {
          model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
            asyncStorageIO('react-native-tensor-flow-model')
          );
          hasModel = true;
          setDetectionModal(model);
          setModelReady(true);

          console.log('Model loaded from storage');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Error loading model from storage');
          console.log(e);
        }

        if (!hasModel) {
          try {
            model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
              'https://model-web-server-domain.com/model.json'
            );

            // Save the model to async storage
            await model.save(asyncStorageIO('react-native-tensor-flow-model'));
            setDetectionModal(model);
            setModelReady(true);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            setHasError(true);
          }
        }
      };

      setFocus(true);
      loadTensor();

      return () => {
        setFocus(false);
      };
    }, [])
  );

 const handleCameraStream = (images, updatePreview, gl) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;

      if (detectionModel && nextImageTensor) {
        try {
          // needs to be expanded to match the models dims or an error occurs
          const tensor4d = nextImageTensor.expandDims(0);
          // needs a cast or an error occurs
          const float32Tensor = tensor4d.cast('float32');
          // const prediction = await detectionModel.predict(nextImageTensor);
          const prediction = await detectionModel.executeAsync(float32Tensor);

          if (prediction && prediction.length > 0) {
            const classes = prediction[0].argMax(-1).print();
            console.log('=== PREDICTION ===');
            console.log(classes);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('ERROR PREDICTING FROM MODEL');
          console.log(e);
        }
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  };

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {tfReady && focus && modelReady && (
          <>
            <TensorCamera
              // Standard Camera props
              style={styles.camera}
              type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
              // Tensor related props
              cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
              cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
              resizeHeight={200}
              resizeWidth={150}
              resizeDepth={3}
              onReady={handleCameraStream}
              autorender={true}
            />
          </>
        )}
        {!tfReady && <Text>Loading ...</Text>}
      </View>
  );
}
```

*** Update ***

Some more Informations about the Model and the Output of the Prediction

moel.json

```js
{
  "format": "graph-model",
  "generatedBy": "2.4.0",
  "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v1.7.0",
  "userDefinedMetadata": {
    "signature": {
      "inputs": {
        "ToFloat:0": {
          "name": "ToFloat:0",
          "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
          "tensorShape": {
            "dim": [
              { "size": "-1" },
              { "size": "-1" },
              { "size": "-1" },
              { "size": "3" }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "outputs": {
        "Postprocessor/convert_scores:0": {
          "name": "Postprocessor/convert_scores:0",
          "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
          "tensorShape": {
            "dim": [{ "size": "-1" }, { "size": "-1" }, { "size": "11" }]
          }
        },
        "Postprocessor/Decode/transpose_1:0": {
          "name": "Postprocessor/Decode/transpose_1:0",
          "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
          "tensorShape": { "dim": [{ "size": "-1" }, { "size": "4" }] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modelTopology": {/*...*/},
  "weightsManifest": [/*...*/],
}
```

Output of prediction (Data Tensor)

```
{"dataId": {"id": 22594}, "dtype": "int32", "id": 17510, "isDisposedInternal": false, "kept": false, "rankType": "3", "shape": [200, 150, 3], "size": 90000, "strides": [450, 3]}

Tensor
    [[[0.0002148, 0.0004637, 0.0005074, 0.0002892, 0.0006514, 0.0002825, 0.000659 , 0.0004711, 0.0006962, 0.0002513, 0.0007014],
      [0.0002115, 0.000315 , 0.0005155, 0.0002003, 0.0006719, 0.0003006, 0.000607 , 0.00035  , 0.000555 , 0.0003226, 0.0011692],
      [0.0002034, 0.0005054, 0.0007887, 0.0003393, 0.0008593, 0.0003684, 0.0009112, 0.0006189, 0.0007553, 0.0006771, 0.0009623],
      ...,
      [0.0031853, 0.0024052, 0.0078735, 0.0032234, 0.0032864, 0.0030518, 0.007637 , 0.0053635, 0.0085449, 0.0039902, 0.0059357],
      [0.0031471, 0.0018387, 0.0050392, 0.0019646, 0.0024433, 0.0026016, 0.0039139, 0.0029011, 0.0051994, 0.0027256, 0.0041809],
      [0.0032482, 0.0017414, 0.0041161, 0.0016489, 0.0021324, 0.001853 , 0.0030632, 0.0022793, 0.0032864, 0.0045204, 0.007637 ]]]
```

Comment: Does the model return the position `topLeft` and `bottomRight` of the detected object?

Comment: how can I check ?

Comment: Well include the output of the model in the question.

Comment: Sry, I don't get it, the output of the prediction or the model json ?

Comment: Yes the prediction, for you to be able to draw the bounding boxes this model has to be able to return the `class of the object` and the `bounding box position of each object`, if it was not trained with this in mind then you cannot do so.

Comment: ok interesting, will update the answer with some more details about the model and the output of the prediction

Comment: I am confused with the model's outputs, its performing object detection yet returning a 3D tensor?

Comment: I was hoping for a result containing the class name and a % of chance and maybe the bbox x,y, width and height or some of it

the tensorflow.js predict function of the model returns a tensor

"Returns: tf.Tensor|tf.Tensor[]|{[name: string]: tf.Tensor}"

Comment: @nixoschu have u solved this issue??

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel not really, we did export the model in a different way and I used "@tensorflow/tfjs-automl" to load the model. After these changes I had the detect method that would resolve in a result with boundary boxes.

Comment: I have to do same thing; did u solve it?

Comment: Not with this library, did it with something else but the performance was very poor when compared to native libraries so we decided to take an image instead and run our test over the image and show the result. Maybe something changed in the mean time.